# how to move the cursor to a specific word in textarea?

Tags: jquery

in the textarea i have followwing lines,

```
hello world. <h2>sub heading</h2>
<img src="" alt="image.jpg"><h3>Test</h3>
More text
<img src="" alt="">
```

i want to be able to click a button that will move the cursor to alt attribute which is empty. if there is "h" tag then are they in proper order.(there should be h1 tag first then h2 tag). if they are not proper order then move the cursor to next "h" tag.(this example move the cursor to h2 tag).
at the end cursor would be move to last alt attribute. then if i click the button again cursor will move to "h2" tag again.
I have the following code,

```
<script type = "text/javascript">            
      (function ($, undefined) {
 $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
    var el = $(this).get(0);
    var pos = 0;
    if('selectionStart' in el) {
        pos = el.selectionStart;
    } else if('selection' in document) {
        el.focus();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
        var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
        Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
        pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
    }
    return pos;
  }
})(jQuery);

function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
if (input.setSelectionRange) {
input.focus();
input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
}
else if (input.createTextRange) {
var range = input.createTextRange();
range.collapse(true);
range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
range.select();
}
 else if(input.createTextRange){
 var range = elt.createTextRange();
 range.move('character', pos);
  range.select(); 
 }
 }

 function setCaretToPos (input, pos) {
 setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
 }

 function nextAlt(input) {
 var current = input.getCursorPosition();
 var search = input.val().substr( ( 0 == current ? 0 : current + 1 ) );
 var pos = current + search.search(/<[a-zA-Z]+(>|.*?[^?]>)/) + 1;
 if (-1 == pos) {
    alert("No elements found");
 } else {
    setCaretToPos(input.get(0), pos);
 }
 }
    </script>
```

text inside the textarea and the button:

```
 <textarea id="textarea">
 hello world. <h2>sub heading</h2>
 <img src="" alt="image.jpg"><h3>Test</h3>
 More text
 <img src="" alt="">
 </textarea>
 <br>
 <a onclick="nextAlt($('#textarea'));">Next</a>
```

Codes above does not work in IE(need to be cross browser). it moves the cursor to different tags but i want to use different condition before placing the curosor to a specific place. for example, 
i want to check the order of the heading tag. if h2 and h3 being used then it should check for h1 tag and move the cursor to h2 tag. then if user click the button again it will move to the alt="" attribute(missing alternative text) not to h3 tag because order of the heading tag is ok after h2. when it reach the end if user click the button again cursor will go back to "h2" tag again.
can someone please help me with that. thanks

Comment: This is tricky to do cross-browser. [Tim Down](http://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down) (a major SO contributor) has a library to help you do it (a jQuery plug-in) called [RangyInputs](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/).

Comment: thanks for the link.. only problem is how do i add my own condition in there for example look for missing alternative text(alt="").. is there anyother way to achieve what im trying to do. i mean without jquery..

Comment: @ user: *"i mean without jquery.."* Then why the `jquery` tag?

Comment: i want the code to be cross browser. as you said its tricky to make it cross browser. i badly need that to be working. at this stage i will use anything. all i need is to be working.

Comment: @ user: I pointed you at the RangyInputs library, which is exactly for this. Have you looked at it? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: in rangyinputs you need to select the text first but I am trying to click button and that will move the cursor to a certain location one after another..

Comment: @ user: The insertion point is a zero-width selection.